# What's wrong with my question? It says too broad but I have a very specific ask

Tags: support

I have a question about my Travel Stack Exchange post: [Which airports require going through immigration for a connecting flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109733/which-airports-require-going-through-immigration-for-a-connecting-flight)

How do I improve it? My question was "Has anyone anywhere compiled a list of which airports make you go through immigration before a connecting flight?" There can easily be a single correct answer - someone providing a link to such a resource. Or tumbleweed if no one is aware of one or it doesn't exist (yet, but may in the future).

Any help on how I could get the answer I seek? There's been other questions in the format of "which somethings" such as [Which European cities are connected by convenient night boat?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35842/which-european-cities-are-connected-by-convenient-night-boat) that were considered okay. What's the difference? Why is one okay and the other isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to prevent individual answers (like you started to get) like 'oh well in Canada you don't" and then "Tanzania does this" in another answer.  Best to change title to something like "Is there a resource indicating whether you need to go through immigration in a given airport?" or "How do I find out if I need to go through immigration when travelling internationally?"

Comment: I modified my answer to add information received in comments; if people followed this procedure, the answer might well become a really informative one.